# Cannot set up audiences containing members of a AD Group on SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, moss, sharepoint-2007

I am having a problem where in SharePoint 2007 after verifying the profile import was successful and the AD group is there, I go to audiences and try to create a rule where the user must be a member of said AD group.  The problem is that when i get to the point of searching for the group to set up the rule, SharePoint can't find that group or any other for that matter.  It just comes up with "TEMPLATE" which is not in AD.

Is there a fix for this issue? Or any suggestions on something to try to get SharePoint to find groups when setting up rules for Audiences?

### UPDATE:

I found that we had two connections to our Active Directory, one pulling users and one pulling groups.  I removed the groups, re ran the full import and removed all of the profiles that were not imported.  Then i went back and tried to set up the Audience again and it worked!!

Not sure what happened or why telling SharePoint to import groups caused Audience to fail, anyone have an answer or idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I resolved this issue by removing one of the Active Directory Connections (the one that was supposed to import groups) and the Audience was able to pull ***some*** groups and users.  After changing the '***Owner***' of the specific audience, I was able to finish creating the Audience where everyone that was supposed to be in it, was.  If the owner is the 'System account' and not specifically on your companies domain, the Audience will not find 100% of the users it is supposed to.  Weird, but thats Microsoft for you.

Comment: Thanks - this helped.  When the owner of the audience was a regular user, I didn't see my group.  When I set the owner of the audience to an admin account, the group was listed.  Looks like something relating to permissions, but is it in Sharepoint or Active Directory?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to create a SharePoint group that has the same name and holds to AD group as it's member? Then add the Sharepoint group to the audience.

Comment: When searching for any group, it doesn't find anything, even SharePoint groups that already existed. :(